# A linear system with inequalities constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

For each $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ think $\mathbb{R}^m$ as the space of real column vectors of size $m$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ as the space of matrices of size $m\times n$.

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $a:\{1,\dots,2^d\} \to \{1\}\times\{0,1\}^d$ be an enumeration (injective and surjective map).

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(d+1)\times 2^d}$ be the matrix whose columns are $a(1),\dots, a(2^d)$.

Is it true that for each $b \in \{1\} \times [0,1]^d$ there exists $x \in [0,+\infty)^{2^d}$ such that
$$
Ax=b?
$$

It is clear that without the constraint on the sign of the components of $x$ the problem has a solution since $\operatorname{rank}(A) = d+1$. Also, for each specific instance of $b$ we could run the simplex algorithm to determine if it as a solution or not. However, I'm not quite sure about how to tackle this problem theoretically to give a proof that has always a solution (running various time the simplex algorithm on various instances always returned a solution, but, of course, it could be just luck). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an $x$ with $x_i\in[0,1]$.

Essentially, you want to solve
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2^d} x_n=1,\quad \sum_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\rfloor\equiv 1\pmod{2}}x_n=b_k
$$
and you can see
$$
x_n=\prod_{k=1}^d f_k(n),\quad f_k(n):=\begin{cases}b_k&\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\rfloor\equiv 1\pmod{2}\\1-b_k&\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\rfloor\equiv 0\pmod{2}\end{cases}
$$
is a solution.

**How to come up with this**  Induct on $d$ and you see each $x_i$ splits into two --- one that contributes to the new equation $\dots=b_{d+1}$ and one doesn't.  So naturally you scale those that contribute by $b_{d+1}$ and the other gets the $1-b_{d+1}$ leftover, and the base case is obvious.